# Why can't PHP mysqli_stmt properties be accessed via foreach or get_object_vars?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
//preparing statement, executing and so on is omitted...
//$this->cur_query_stmt is object returned by prepare() function
var_dump($this->cur_query_stmt);
foreach($this->cur_query_stmt as $k=>$v){
  var_dump($k);
  var_dump($v);
  }
```

The output of this code:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#6 (9) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(7)
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["param_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
}
string(13) "affected_rows"
NULL
string(9) "insert_id"
NULL
string(8) "num_rows"
NULL
string(11) "param_count"
NULL
string(11) "field_count"
NULL
string(5) "errno"
NULL
string(5) "error"
NULL
string(8) "sqlstate"
NULL
string(2) "id"
NULL
```

**Can anybody explain why all values are returned as NULL?**

I can get them by calling $this->cur_query_stmt->$this->affected_rows, but when trying to get them in foreach or get_object_vars function I get NULL's. I am confused, please help!

Comment: Just curious, why do you want them in a loop?

Comment: Actually I want to get them by get_object_vars function, but since it gave me nulls I tried to get them in a loop. I am storing it to return by my function that executes queries

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_stmt has no _constructor() to generate its property values. To get "affected_rows", you have to call $this->cur_query_stmt->$this->affected_rows instead.

Comment: That code is executed after ..prepare($query) and ..execute(), so it is not connected with not generating values in _constructor(). Moreover I did var_dump($this->cur_query_stmt) and it's output shows that properties are actually set.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I think this is what you trying to do:

```
   array_result=array();
   foreach ($stmt as $key => $value) {
       $array_result[$key]=$stmt->$key;
    }
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: for what i understand he's trying to obtaing all the details of the result of the prepared sentence, this will return all the results at once.